# Programmatically copy a cell from Excel using VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, excel, com

**Without**:

- MFC
- ATL

using **COM**, with **pure C++**, steps taken thus far:

```
//steps above omitted

_ApplicationPtr application(__uuidof(Excel::Application));

//omitted

const BSTR wcharFileName = SysAllocString(L"...");

application->Workbooks->Open(wcharFileName);

application->put_Visible(10, true);
```

**Question:**

- How to then copy a cell, for instance A4, B4 and C4, into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216388/en-us

Comment: MAN! Thanks a lot! I wish I could vote twice - hope this question helps others :)

Answer (score 0):

I earlier posted that

"For Excel - COM using C++

http://shaktisaran.tech.officelive.com/ExcelCOM.aspx

It also has Windows Programming tutorials."

I've deleted that post because it wouldn't help easily.

I'm providing more info related to example on web-site,

In ExcelProcessor.cpp

ReadRange function reads a range of Excel cells but you need to read a cell of data.

ShowAddedCells function writes to an Excel cell which you can use like below.

In ShowAddedCells function,

```
//Comment the following
/*
DISPID dispidPUT = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;

DISPPARAMS dparams = {vDblVal, &dispidPUT, 1, 1};

EXCEPINFO excepinfo;

hr = pXlCell->Invoke(dispID,
    IID_NULL,
    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
    DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT,
    &dparams,
    NULL,
    &excepinfo,
    NULL);
*/

//Add the following
DISPPARAMS dparams = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};

EXCEPINFO excepinfo;

VARIANT vResult;
VariantInit(&vResult);

hr = pXlCell->Invoke(dispID,
    IID_NULL,
    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
    DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
    &dparams,
    &vResult,
    &excepinfo,
    NULL);

//You get the cell value in vResult
```

So you create a ReadCell function like ShowAddedCells function.